# How to get SELECTED value from dropdown in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the selected value of a dropdown menu and store it in a variable, but i'm getting an 'index undefined' error.

I want to be able to take the data taken from the dropdown menu and push the data to a table based on the selected value.

```
<form id='dropdownform' method='post' name='dropdownform'>
**<select name='dropdownlist' id='dropdownlist'>**
<option value=''> --All Years-- </option>
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($connection,"6nationsDB");
$dropdownlist = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM results GROUP BY year");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dropdownlist)) {
    print("<option value='" . $row[year] . "'>" . $row[year] . "</option>");
}
?>
</form>
<?php

print("</select>");
print("</form>");
print('<table>');
print('<tr>');
print('<th>Round</th>');
print('<th>Date</th>');
print('<th></th>');
print('<th>Home Team</th>');
print('<th></th>');
print('<th></th>');
print('<th></th>');
print('<th>Away Team</th>');
print('<th></th>');
print('<th>Venue</th>');
print('</tr>');

**$select_val = $_POST['dropdownlist'];**
if($select_val == '') {
    $resultset = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM results ORDER BY rnd, date");
}
else {
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultset)) {

                print('<tr>');
                print('<td>' . $row['rnd'] . '</td>');
                print('<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>');

                $homeTeamResults = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from teams where id = " . $row['HomeTeamID']);
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($homeTeamResults);

                print('<td>' . "<img src='images/" . $row['HomeTeamID'] . ".png' height='15px'>" . '</td>');
                print('<td>' . $row2['name'] . '</td>');

                print('<td>' . $row['HomeTeamScore'] . '</td>');
                print('<td>-</td>');
                print('<td>' . $row['AwayTeamScore'] . '</td>');

                $awayTeamResults = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from teams where id = " . $row['AwayTeamID']);
                $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($awayTeamResults);

                print('<td>' . $row3['name'] . '</td>');
                print('<td>' . "<img src='images/" . $row['AwayTeamID'] . ".png' height='15px'>" . '</td>');
                print('<td>' . $row['venue'] . '</td>');

            }
}

        print('</table>');

?>[![this is the error message][1]][1]
```

any and all help would be appreciated, I'm quite new to PHP

Comment: If `$_POST['dropdownlist']` produces an undefined index error then that value wasn't posted to the server.  How have you confirmed that it's being posted?

Comment: This is due to not passing value in option. Pass the value in the option tag. Try echoing value once and test it

Comment: I know the dropdown list is pulling data from the server because the dropdown list is populated from the database

Comment: @KieranRippyThompson: Whether or not the `<select>` is *populated* isn't the error.  You have code which is attempting to use the selected value when no selected value is present.  For example, a common mistake which results in this error could be if the same code both displays and handles the form.  In that case the error would occur when displaying the form because that happens before the form is posted.